# What happens if I do not close read end or write end of pipe?

Tags: linux, command, pipe

Let's say I have:

command1 | command2

and forgot to have command2 process close write end of the pipe.

If so, will command1 will keep reading from command2 since it does not know when to stop reading?

What happens if I forgot to have command1 process close read end of the pipe?

Will command2 process keep on waiting for someone to read because it thinks some process is trying to read from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have your input and output mixed up.

command1 is only writing to the pipe that command2 is reading from -- and while that pipe is active (i.e. command2 hasn't died or actively closed its' input descriptor), command1 will keep trying to send its' output there (or until command1 itself finishes).

If command1 finishes, and it has managed to send all of its' output to STDOUT (which is the input end of the pipe), it will exit, and that end of the pipe will be closed. If command2 is still reading from its' STDIN (which is the output end of the pipe), it will be able to get the last of the data, and will see an end-of-file condition.

If, on the other hand, command2 closes its' input manually, or exits, before command1 has finished sending, the next time command1 tries to write to STDOUT, it will get a "broken pipe" error.

Hope this clears things up a bit.

Comment: I believe the person who asked the question was wondering if they used the `pipe()` system call, as they asked about what happens if an end was not closed.